# What strategies can be implemented to prevent students from cheating while completing online assignments?

Tags: lesson-ideas, curriculum-design

As an educator, I've created a course with assignments featuring automated tests via browxy.com, an online solution. However, I'm concerned that students may seek solutions from external sources, such as ChatGPT, compromising the integrity of the assessments. I'm currently exploring strategies to mitigate this issue, such as modifying the problems. Have you encountered similar challenges, and if so, how have you addressed them effectively?

Answer (score 4):

You first used the term "assignment", and then "assessment". I would start by asking the question of yourself, which is the predominant purpose of the activity?

I don't think here are any great answers to be had if you want your labs to be a significant source of grades.  It used to be that it was practical to have lab coding assignments as the bulk of the grades, but I suspect those days are gone. LLMs can competently code essentially any good lab that we can create, because good labs are deeply organized things, and they work towards LLMs strengths.

The best way I've encountered to deal with it so far is to keep assessments to things the students do in front of you, ideally on paper. Labs, then, become rich learning environments in which to wrestle with, and hopefully master, the material.

Then inform students of the structure.  *These labs are practice for your tests. I strongly recommend using then as learning opportunities. I've put a lot of work into making sure that they'll be good ones. That said, if you cheat, it will come back at you on the tests, which is where you prove that mastery to me."

This setup has the side benefit of encouraging students to think about how they can best arrange their own learning, and making explicit how your course materials are designed to support them.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment!! That is a very good strategy! To have a stage where the need to be in front of you and tell them that if they cheat on the excercises they are cheating themselves